# Umbraco cannot start. A connection string is configured -running correctly in local but error on hosted one

Tags: asp.net, database-connection, umbraco

My project is working perfectly on local host but I am trying to host it on iis and following error is showing[image]

Steps which I have tried so far:

1.checked my connection string which is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Server=EIL-IT-360-39\SQLEXPRESS;Database=umbraco_16_6;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

2.Using window authentication to login into my DB.

I have also refrered given sites but could not found desired solution:

[Umbraco cannot start. A connection string is configured but the Umbraco cannot connect to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847901/)

[Umbraco cannot start after switching to local SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874572/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help..my problem is now solved ..though it solved by adding a new user with some password in my ssms and then adding same in connection string as

```
<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="..database=umbraco_16_6;user id=sa;password=*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

then,my umbraco password was not accepted at login screen[even though I haven't made any changes in that password]..for which I tried to update hashed password and [other](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/4790) options..but none of those worked for me..
Then I have had a backup of my DB..which saved my project..and now I am able to login into my Umbraco site as well as hosted it successfully on my network.

Answer (score 3):

Check which identity your website is running under in IIS:

- open IIS
- got to Applications Pools in the tree on the left
- find your website in the list
- go to Advanced Settings
- switch the Identity to **Network Service** rather than **ApplicationPoolIdentity**

I believe this is the user which runs the website. If this doesn't work, you may want to check that your selected Identity has access to the database.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a permissions/connection issue. Usually this is because either the IIS server can't see the machine "EIL-IT-360-39" (try using the machine's IP address instead). Or the windows authentication isn't working.

If you're using integrated authentication, the site will be connecting as your application pool identity account. You need to make sure that the application pool account has access to read and write to your database. There is a tutorial here on how to do this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx

Comment: yes,,iis is on same machine..as the database...window authenication might be the problem...plzz suggest some solution:)

Comment: though my problem is solved ..but still upvotting your answer for your effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

please provide the same user name and password that u created while instating umbraco Db.and yor visualstudio connection string should be like

```
<connectionStrings>
        <remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />
    <!--<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="server=PALPIN-022\SQLEXPRESS;database=Databasename;user id=UmbracoDbname;password='umbracodbpassword'" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->    
        <!-- Important: If you're upgrading Umbraco, do not clear the connection string / provider name during your web.config merge. -->
    </connectionStrings>
```

**note**: password should in `"''"` double quotes inside single quotes.